# ERROR: Could not build wheels for phik, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

While running this command on command prompt:

```
PS D:\Mitali> pip install pandas-profiling
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for phik, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The entire error looks as:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: phik
Building wheel for phik (pyproject.toml) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqi_0g29r'
cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-prmn_pyb\phik_c27377b089f2467988f10191570c8033
```

Comment: Will you please share the full error, in the question?

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
pip install phik==0.11.1   
pip install pandas-profiling
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).